# Pandas skip missing values in map function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Any help on how can I skip missing values in my world field. I thought na_action='ignore' would help, but it doesn't for my case .

```
df['world'] = df['world'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('L.locoMoco'),na_action='ignore')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `world` is an object column, call `str.rstrip` directly.

```
df['world'] = df['world'].str.rstrip('L.locoMoco')
```

If the column is one of objects, NaNs are preserved. However, if you have numeric values, they're are coerced to NaNs, so if this is not intended behaviour, I'd suggest, either

1. Coercing those values to string (to preserve them), or
2. Using slower alternatives like a `for` loop or `apply`.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Saved my time. Thank you so much! :) @COLDSPEED